# How to flush named pipe(FIFO) in non-blocking mode in busybox shell script?

Tags: bash, embedded-linux, busybox

I tried using "cat" and "dd" commands to flush the FIFO and both commands blocks the operation.

Below are the commands used to flush,

## Create FIFO

```
mkfifo tmp.fifo
```

## Using "cat" command

```
cat tmp.fifo
```

OR even using file descriptor with cat command like,

```
exec 200<> tmp/fifo; 
cat <&200 > /dev/null
```

## Using "dd" command

```
dd if=tmp.fifo of=/dev/null
```

## Note:

"dd" command works well (doesn't block) in Linux PC terminal with the help of 'iflag' like,

```
dd if=tmp/fifo iflag=nonblock of=/dev/null
```

(!) But this doesn't work with busybox's version of `dd`. How can I achieve it using `busybox`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy to check whether/how this is possible, just by looking at the busybox source: [No references to `O_NONBLOCK` exist anywhere in the busybox codebase.](https://github.com/progrium/busybox/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=O_NONBLOCK)

Thus: With busybox alone, this is not possible.

---

Now, what you *can* do (*if* your kernel's behavior is appropriate -- POSIX doesn't specify behavior of named pipes in this mode, leaving it implementation-defined) is open the pipeline with `O_RW` (so it doesn't need a writer) and perform a blocking read, with another process killing this after a timeout:

```
exec 5<>yourpipe
cat <&5 >/dev/null & cat_pid=$!
sleep 1
kill "$cat_pid"
```

It's an ugly, inefficient, and questionably portable hack -- but without adding extra dependencies (Python, Perl, a tiny C helper), it's what you've got.

Comment: "No references to O_NONBLOCK exist anywhere in the busybox codebase.".  For some reason I find this fact fascinating.